# i can't connect to Azure database in QT

Tags: c, qt, odbc

My database is on an Azure server. And I'm trying to connect to it via an ODBC driver (by the way, I tried to install it manually, but I couldn't get it. They say it's built in). I get the following error: **"Data source not found and no default ODBC driver specified: Unable to connect"**

```
dataBaseKnowFood = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
QString connectString = QStringLiteral("myconnectionstring");
dataBaseKnowFood.setDatabaseName(connectString);
dataBaseKnowFood.setPassword("dgf");
dataBaseKnowFood.setUserName("gidgfsg");
if (!dataBaseKnowFood.open())
{
    QMessageBox::critical(this, "Programm", dataBaseKnowFood.lastError().text());
}
```

Comment: Can you post your connection string? I would assume the error to be there.

Comment: `No default ODBC driver specified` cannot make us to blame Qt. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849887/specify-a-default-driver-for-odbc

Comment: I do not understand you @Alexander V

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It was required to update this driver and indicate the version of the updated driver in the connection string.